# Pure JavaScript Frontend and NodeJS Backend

Tags: javascript, web-applications, frontend

I have built a school project which was a basic full stack application last semester using React, Redux, and NodeJS with Express. I want to learn to create a full stack application without any frontend framework like React/Angular. I want my frontend to pure JavaScript. My backend will be Node/Express.

My question - since I am not using Redux, how can I implement the concept of "Predictable State Container" without Redux? Those who do not use Redux, how are they managing states?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Your question is too vague and cannot be objectively answered in a couple of paragraphs. Please read [ask].

Comment: Short answer: yes, you can easily implement something like Redux for a vanilla JS project. While not precisely answering your question, [this is an accessible article inspired by a discussion on Reddit](https://typeofnan.dev/learn-basics-redux-by-writing-your-own-version-30-lines/) that might help you understand what Redux does so you can replicate it for your project.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, I believe this place is for us to learn.

Comment: @amdouglas thank you so much! Definitely gives me somewhere to start. Exactly what I was looking for.